# Plank dock stops showing up after screen resize Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, launcher, display-resolution, plank

I'm having an issue with the Plank dock (launcher) on Ubuntu 20.04. I have a configuration with the "Autohide" feature "on". Once I do any configuration change to the desktop (i.e. switching on/of an external monitor or changing the resolution of external/internal screen), the dock will not show up anymore on the mouse over, as it used to work normally.

The only solution so far is that I can start another instance (and have two, one hidden, one working, showing an icon of the other one), eventually kill the first Plank process and re-launch it, so it works again.

It also happens when I put my laptop to sleep mode and then reconnect it back to the dock with external monitors.

Even if I already have a quick fix, that is very frustrating.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Been having the same issue here. When I connect or disconnect my extarnal USB-C screen I loose plank.

Only way I found to "fix" it was to run a `killall plank` followed by restarting plank from the application menu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is what I do now, manually. Wonder if there is a way to automate this process, i.e. to automatically kill/instantiate on any desktop layout change? Interestingly screen rotation does not seem to affect Plank.